# How do I stop my ssh tunnel when it is in the background?

Tags: ssh-tunnel

I'm using this ssh command:

`ssh -fnN -L $LOCALPORT:$REMOTEHOST:$REMOTEPORT $HOST`

This creates my ssh connection in the background and forwards that port to the remote host through another host. This is great, and allows me to use my service behind a firewall by connecting to a server which can access both networks.

I need to stop this ssh connection when done, and I'm not sure how.

Comment: For most cases better solutions (master mode, automatic termination) are here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83806/19702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the `PID` with the `ps` command and send it a QUIT signal with the `kill` command.

Find the `PID` with:

```
ps -o pid,cmd | grep ssh
```

Send the `QUIT` signal with:

```
kill -QUIT <pid>
```

Comment: I was thinking there was something more to it. Probably overthinking it. Thanks.

Comment: this didn't work for me, but this other answer did: https://superuser.com/questions/87014/how-do-i-remove-an-ssh-forwarded-port/87019

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found is following to kill all the tunnels:

`ps -o pid,cmd|grep "ssh -L"|grep -v grep|awk '{print $1}'|xargs kill`

1. Gets id and command of all processes
2. Filter for ssh -L
3. gets the process id and kills it